# Transiciones de pantalla fallan en react Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

les pido que por favor me ayuden, estoy realizando un Aplicación con react native y al momento que realizo una navigation.navigate(PantallaObjetivo) me sale un efecto muy feo entre que hace el cambio de pantalla, quisiera saber a que se debe, ya que he probado muchas cosas, incluso añadí transiciones y igual sigue permaneciendo el problema.

aquí dejo el enlace del video donde se explica de mejor manera el problema

https://codersgt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/SVID_20210414_002905_1.mp4

[image: Imagen]

Desde ya les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: cual es el efecto? alguna imagen -.-

Comment: Buen día @OsAndNoTi en una imagen no te podría mostrar muy bien pero aquí te dejo el enlace de un video  https://codersgt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/SVID_20210414_002905_1.mp4 Saludos